# Проблема с list.add

Tags: c#, list

Недавно столкнулся с ошибкой
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
Можете помочь поправить, ума не приложу?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<test> tests;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tests.Add(new test());
        tests[0].ints.Add(123);
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class test
        {
        public List<int> ints;
    }
}
```

Comment: tests[0] может просто tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неинициализированный список ints в вашем классе.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class test
{
    public List<int> ints = new List<int>();
}
```